# Keeping config files synced across multiple pc's

Tags: configuration, synchronization

I have a few different linux machines and a lot of **config** files *(and folders)* on each.

For example:

```
~/.ssh/config
~/.config/openbox/rc.xml
~/.config/openbox/autostart.sh
~/.scripts/ ( folder )
~/.bashrc
...etc
```

Is there a simple and elegant method to keep these files synced between my machines *( one has no internet access )*?

Also, some files will need a more advanced syncing process, as they will have to differ slightly... for example:

My desktop keyboard has a range of hotkeys, where my laptop has almost none. I use `XF86Mail` to open thunderbird on my desktop, but <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> on my laptop.

My Home Desktop and Work Desktop are both more "multiple user" orientated, where my Laptop is just for me. So on my laptop, I tend to keep the 'rc.xml' file for openbox at `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` but on the desktops at `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keep the files under version control. This has multiple benefits, including facilitating keeping files synchronized (commit on one machine, update on the others) and keeping a history of changes (so you can easily find out what broke a program that worked last month).

I use CVS and synchronize the repositories with Unison or sneakernet, but that's because I've been doing this since a time before widely-available distributed version control. Anyone starting now should use a proper **distributed version control** tool, such as bazaar, darcs, git, mercurial, ...

Managing files that need to differ between machines is always a bit of a pain. If the configuration language allows conditionals, use them. Otherwise, if there is an include mechanism, use it to split the configuration file into a machine-dependent part and a shared part. Keep all the machine-dependent parts in a separate directory (something like `~/.local/NAME/`) which is always referred to through a symbolic link (`~/.here` -> `local/NAME` on each machine). I have a few files that are generated by a script in the shared part from parameters kept in the machine-specific part; this precludes modifying these files indirectly through a GUI configuration interface. Avoid configuring things in `/etc`, it's harder to synchronize between machines.

Comment: I use `git` for this purpose. [my repo](http://github.com/xenoterracide/dot_etc) for `~/.etc` I also have a `~/.usr` and a `~/.var` I wish that these directories were standard so KDE would stop throwing all tmp/var/config/etc files under .kde. so hard to know where what I want is in my home directory.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the [version control answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/keeping-config-files-synced-across-multiple-pcs/1625#1625), but another method I've been experimenting with recently is [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/). It's essentially a version control system that automatically syncs between all your machines, so if you edit a file on one computer you'll see the changes reflected on your other computers in a couple seconds, without needing to commit on the former and update on the latter.

Their free [basic plan](http://www.dropbox.com/pricing) is 2GB, so I use it to version my configuration files and chat logs

Comment: the major benefit i see here is that it's much easier to setup-up.

Answer (score 3):

[Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) and [Cfengine](http://www.cfengine.org/) are two good tools for syncing files (and a lot more..)

Comment: There's also [chef](http://github.com/opscode/chef) but these tools are really for managing a large number of machines, probably overkill for 2 or 3 systems

Answer (score 1):

Today, one could get the best of the first (dvcs) and second (dropbox) responses with [sparkleshare](http://sparkleshare.org/), which provides a dropbox-like user experience with git-based storage behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

[filetailor](https://github.com/k4j8/filetailor) is an open-source Python program for this exact issue. Based on a YAML configuration file, it can make small changes to the files using device-specific variables or using device-specific comments in the files.

Disclaimer: I had this same issue and made filetailor to solve it.